# Can I support both Nhibernate and RavenDb at the same time?

Tags: nhibernate, ravendb

I'm developing an app that's already running on Nhibernate, but I'm considering using RavenDb to handle some use cases that I'm finding hard to implement on a relational database. (e.g. dynamic fields without using EAV)

I've read this recommended on [this post](http://ayende.com/blog/4776/support-dynamic-fields-with-nhibernate-and-net-4-0) by Ayende on the topic. I'm unsure though as to whether this will be practical in the long run and what common pitfalls there are in having to support 2 databases just to get dynamic fields for my application.

Comment: Are these dynamic fields queryable? If so, that changes the requirements.

Comment: @JosephDaigle +1 very relevant question. Jonn, before settling on an approach, have a think a bit more about what you want to do with this data after it has been stored. EAV (or variants thereof) might be excessively normalised if you wanted to do complex querying. You might have to do multiple joins into your 'skinny' table to execute a complex query. Is it absolutely essential (in your requirements) to go fully dynamic? Interesting question though. I hadn't seen the Ayende post before for nhibernate / dynamic storage.

Comment: It should be queryable to an extent. The data won't be used in any domain logic, but it will likely be used for reporting purposes. It is essential that we come up with something dynamic. This is the common "we don't know what other fields each client needs so we want them to be able to enter what they want on their own" that EAV attempts to solve. EAV has so many pitfalls though that I don't want to even make the attempt this time around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the link from Ayende, he is not advocating having two databases. Merely that the schema would be extended to allow additional metadata about the entity to be stored in a separate table. If you are talking about having a mixed-mode DA layer with parts going to NHibernate and parts to RavenDB you are potentially going to be getting into distributed transaction territory - this could be a significant increase in scope for you.

You could also consider adding an additional column to your entity's table to allow you to serialise an object into it - it could be a dictionary for example (you could even use Json). This will be ok for you if you don't need to query *across* multiple entities afterwards. If you only needed that data when you were viewing a *particular* entity you'd be ok.

I've used this approach for storing user's preferences. I don't need to 'find all users whose preference category X has value Y', I just need to say 'tell me all the values of all the preferences for user A'.

**Edit - storing XML**
For the serialized object in the database, you could use the xml data type. Link from msdn below:-
[Implementing XML in SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189887%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

This can go up to 2GB so you shouldn't run out of space to store lots of dynamic values. The fluent mapping for this field would look something like this:-

```
Map(x=>x.FieldForSerializedThing).CustomType("StringClob")
                                     .Column("[FieldForSerializedThing]")
                                     .Not.Nullable()
                                     .Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore);
```

The entity would have a field like this:-

```
public virtual System.String FieldForSerializedThing
{ 
    get { return _fieldForSerializedThing; }
    set { _fieldForSerializedThing = value; }
}
```

I'm sure there are other ways to do the serialization but this could get you out of a hole (example above is for SQL Server by the way).

Comment: Well yeah. I'd hoped that distributed transactions would be less hellish than EAV designs if it were being recommended. Going the serialized path, wouldn't this mean that I would have to limit my custom fields to the max size that SQL can support (e.g. 8000 characters)?